# .NET 7 Razor Pages binding decimal Dutch Culture set posted model as null

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages, model-binding

I have a website using .NET 7 and Razor pages. I have the following case. I have a table with multiple rows. And when a value(a decimal or DateTime) changes I need to post this to the backend.

The culture has been set to nl-NL. Therefore the values in the input look like this:

- Decimal: 2,01
- DateTime: 30-12-2022

On the Backend, I have a class containing a decimal and DateTime. And a Post method as followed

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostUpdateAsync([FromBody] UpdateModel model)
{
    return new JsonResult(new { success=true});
}

public class UpdateModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool? Approved { get; set; }
}
```

But when I use the following AJAX call to post the data, the model in the Post is **null**. When I do not publish the Date and Quantity then it works.

This is the AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/organisation/orderproposal?handler=RandomNumber",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: 1, date: "29-08-1988", quantity: "2,01" }),
    headers: {
        RequestVerificationToken:
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
    },
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

I do not understand why this fails when I have a Form everything with values like this work. But I do not see how I can use a form as I have unlimited rows in the table.

Comment: looks to me that you send strings here but its a number and a date. stringify will handle that correctly if you just use a number/date type here. Don't try to use strings and anything culture related. Json is/should be culture ignorant.

Comment: What I do is use jQuery $(element).val() to get values from input and send those. These are strings when I use .val().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your input. It got me to my answer. I just to functions to get the number and date correctly.

I used this to get the decimal:

```
Globalize.parseNumber($(element).val());
```

And as I was using flatpickr for the date I used this code to get the correct format:

```
var d = flatpickr.parseDate($(element).val(), "d-m-Y");
return flatpickr.formatDate(d, "Y-m-d");
```

This did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you use the wrong format which causes model binding failure.

Change your code like below:

```
<script>
    function ClickFunc()
    {
        var datestring= "29-08-1988";
        var dateOut = datestring.split("-");
        var dateToSend = new Date(dateOut[1] + "/" + dateOut[0] + "/" + dateOut[2]);
        var quantity = "2,01";
        var quantityToSend = quantity.replaceAll(".", "").replaceAll(",", ".");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/organisation/orderproposal?handler=RandomNumber",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: 1, date: dateToSend, quantity: quantityToSend }),
            headers: {
                RequestVerificationToken:
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Rena, this helped me get the correct answer. As I need a way to be culture independent I found Globalize.parseNumber() and flatpickr.formatDate().